# Resources for JVM Tuning

Tags: jvm, performance

Anybody knows a good book or two (or resources) for JVM Tuning?

I am struggling to find any. I stumbled upon Apress Java EE 5 Performance Management and Optimization, but there was not much in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't books, but, I find Sun's various performance whitepapers to be quite enlightening.

- [Java Tuning Whitepaper](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/tuning.html)
- [Java SE 6 Performance Whitepaper](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/6_performance.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a chapter in JBoss in Action, chapter 14, Tuning the JBoss Application server that explains some techniques of managing JVM heaps.